# Create Matrix from pixel array in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a unsigned short array which I would like to median filter using opencv (it seems to have one of the most efficient filters around)

However I can't seem to create a matrix from the array.
I've tried the Mat(int _rows, int _cols, int _type, void* _data, size_t _step=AUTO_STEP) constructor using:

```
Mat(rows,cols,IPL_DEPTH_16U,myShortArray,2);
```

But it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
Mat m(rows, cols, CV_16U, myShortArray);
```